# Woocommerce - change the image link from product page to external buy link, but keep the title linked to the product page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I`m using Woocommerce 3.7 and on the shop category page the product image and the title are linked to the product page (standard).
Is it possible to keep the title linked to the product page and change only the image link to the external / affiliate link?
The theme I'm currently ussing is Divi and has no custom Woocmmerce templates.
Thank you!

My issue is quite similar to the issue resolved here, but here both the image link and the title link are redirected to the external / affiliate link. [Woocommerce remove the link on the product title and replace it with the link : External Product / Affiliation> Product URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55358503/woocommerce-remove-the-link-on-the-product-title-and-replace-it-with-the-link)

Comment: I think it would be bad user interface to have the image link to a different place than the title and its important to be clear where you're sending users. It would make more sense to have both the image and the title link to the same page (product-single) and then offer the external/affiliate link there as an option. Transparency is important if you're going to bounce them to a different site and it could possibly hurt sales if they don't come back. I'm sure you have a good plan but I just wanted to put that out there just in case :)

Comment: In case of an "affiliate site" the user will go to the external link in the end. With this option the user can go directly to the store that sales the product. It's more likely that the the user will click the image than on the titile. If I keep the link to the product page in the tile I will have also a direct link to each product page. Is there any impact on Google if I`m chaning both links (image and title) to the external link? I will have no direct links to the product pages.